# How to reference nested requires in app.yaml for App Engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a `index.php` with a

```
require 'myfolder/folder/lib1.php';
```

So in `app.yaml` I reference:

```
- url: /myfolder/folder/lib1.php
  script: myfolder/folder/lib1.php
```

but this `lib1.php` does another `require 'lib2.php';` at same folder level `/myfolder/folder/`. So it trows error 500 because it can't find `lib2.php`.
How can I properly reference them both in app.yaml?

Comment: Why do you think you need to list required library files inside the `app.yaml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 500 was thrown basically because Google App Engine for php doesn't support CURL extension used in the Facebook php SDK. Nothing related to app.yaml includes.
I forked the official fb sdk git and I'm patching a solution right now.

Comment: My solution is already pulled to the official SDK
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/pull/77

Comment: awesome - can you ping me offline?

Answer (score 4):

Your app.yaml file is for routing requests from incoming URLs to the initial script you want to use to process the request.

You don't need to add routings for each and every *.php file that you want to include from one script to another.

For example, look at the [app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress) example for running wordpress. It just has the URLs that clients will access, but not all of the php scripts used by wordpress.

Comment: Ok, Im going a little clueless here...
I'm trying to include the facebook API but it shows error 500 all the time.

Comment: @Veilkrand: That is independent to `app.yaml`. Instead consider to use *composer*/*packagist* for PHP package management for an easy way. http://getcomposer.org - https://packagist.org/search/?q=facebook

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is most likely independent to Google App Engine. On Google App Engine, the [standard rules of PHP file-inclusion](http://php.net/include) still applies. The only potential difference here is that the files are read-only (but that should not pose any problems in your case).

So if `lib1.php` requires `lib2.php` you need to require the later before you require the other. That is standard PHP behavior:

```
require 'myfolder/folder/lib2.php'; 
require 'myfolder/folder/lib1.php';
```

To learn more what exactly caused the 500 error on Google App Engine, [consider downloading the log and look into it](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Logs). This is also independent to Google App Engine, because that is the best suggestion one can give with any webserver on 500 errors.